# Try to Find the Missing Conditions of An Inequality Proof

Tags: inequality, contest-math

If $$(a^5-a^3+3)(b^5-b^3+3)(c^5-c^3+3)\ge 3(a+b+c)^2 \quad  . $$ Prove that $a^5-a^3\ge a^2-1$.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rce2.png)

it is easy to find the statement is wrong when $(a,b,c)=(-2,-2,1)$.

Noticed that  $$a^5-a^3\ge a^2-1$$ 
is equivalent to $$(a^3-1)(a^2-1)\ge 0$$
or $a\ge -1$,
then by their symmety
$a,b,c\ge -1$

So I tried to add "  $a,b,c\ge -1$",but it seemed that the conclusion is obviously right

then I guess $a\ge b\ge c$

but I failed to prove it

So I wonder how to prove or other possible missing conditions

Comment: This starting problem is wrong, which says that all the rest it's absurd.

Comment: can you give me a counterexample when $a\ge b\ge c$

Comment: I posted it. See please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(a,b,c)=(-1.1,-2,-2)$.

Hence, $(a^5-a^3+3)(b^5-b^3+3)(c^5-c^3+3)\ge 3(a+b+c)^2$ is true, $a\geq b\geq c$ is true,

but $a^5-a^3\geq a^2-1$ is wrong.